# Error starting Hyper-V VM

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, bios

I'm trying to start a VM on a new Hyper-V installation and I'm receiving the following error:

> The virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.  The following actions may help you resolve the problem:
>
> 1) Verify that the processor of the physical computer has a supported version of hardware-assisted virtualization.
>
> 2) Verify that hardware-assisted virtualization and hardware-assisted data execution protection are enabled in the BIOS of the physical computer.  (If you edit the BIOS to enable either setting, you must turn off the power to the physical computer and then turn it back on.  Resetting the physical computer is not sufficient.)
>
> 3) If you have made changes to the Boot Configuration Data store, review these changes to ensure that the hypervisor is configured to launch automatically.

My machine supports virtualization at the hardware level and it is enabled in BIOS.

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intel**

- Must have Virtualization Technology enabled in the BIOS, sometimes this is referred to as VT or virtualization assist
- Must have No-Execute enabled in the BIOS, sometime this is referred to as NX or Execute Disable

Enabling Virtualization Technologies requires a cold boot of the machine after changing the setting *TURN MACHINE OFF WAIT 2 SEC TURN BACK ON*

**AMD**

- Must be revision F3 or greatter or must be F2 with BIOS support.  Presence or absence of SVM Disable or other virtualization options in the bios does not ensure presence of BIOS support.  You should contact the OEM to ensure support of Hyper-V.
- Some AMD BIOS's have options to enable/disable SVM (virtualization assistance)

  *Some BIOS's list this as SVM Disable and it's a double negative, ie you want to disable SVM disable to enable SVM.

  *Some BIOS's list this as Secure Virtualization, thus enabling Secure Virtualization will enable SVM
- Must have No-Execute enabled in the BIOS, sometime this is refered to as NX or Execute Disable

[ [Answer Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/ce2fbf98-91a4-413d-80aa-ed0cd5cc68d7/) ]